# mysql results numbering in PHP with custom pagination

Tags: php, pagination

I have PHP code in basic custom MVC design that is intended to search for records in a MySQL database and then return/output the results in a paginated page. My problem is that the results in page 1 are numbered 1 -20 as well as those in page 2, page 3 etc.

Ideally results in page 2 should be 21-40, those in page 3 should be 41-60...etc

Here is the code snippet of the controller

```
function getCitation() {
    $limit = 20;
    $currentpage = isset($_GET['page']) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
    $start_from =((($currentpage*$limit)-$limit)+1);
    $term = isset($_GET['searchterm']) ? $_GET['searchterm'] : null;
    //if(isset($_GET['mysearch']))
    if(isset($_GET['search1']) && empty($term) && ($_GET['choice'] == 'title' || $_GET['choice'] == 'author')){
        header ('Location: ' . '../index');     
    }
    $this->view->getCitation = $this->model->getCitation($term,$start_from,$limit);
    //The line below is critical for pagination in view.
    $this->view->getPages = $this->model->getPages($term, $limit);
    $this->view->render('search/index');
 }
```

The Model looks like this

```
public function getCitation($term, $start_from, $limit){
    $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM citations_new WHERE title 
        LIKE ? LIMIT {$start_from}, {$limit}");
    $sth->execute(array('%'.$term.'%'));
    return $rows = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
public function getPages($term, $limit){
    echo $term;
    $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT Count(*) FROM citations_new WHERE title 
        LIKE ?");
    //echo 1;
    $sth->execute(array('%'.$term.'%'));
    $results = $sth->fetchColumn();
    $total_records = $results;
    return $total_pages = ceil($total_records/$limit);
}
```

The view looks like this:

```
$x=1;
while($row = array_shift($this->getCitation())){
    echo $x++;
    echo $row['title'] . '<br>';
}
for($i=1; $i<=$this->getPages; $i++):?>
    <a href="?searchterm=<?php echo $_GET['searchterm'].'&search1=Submit+Query&page=' . $i; ?>">
    <?php echo $i;?></a>
<?php endfor;?>
```

When i echo-out the line `$start_from =((($currentpage*$limit)-$limit)+1);` on the controller, i am able to see the correct start_number. How can i get my results be numbered sequentially?

Comment: add an `ORDER BY ` to your sql statement?

Comment: @Dale I have added `ORDER BY ID DESC` but nothing has changed

Comment: code igniter provides the pagination library so please use that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I misunderstood, didn't you solve this yourself ?
Why can't you set the counter as you did the test ?

Adding a bit to the answer,
so we need to set an array of the viewdata, an add to it the proper info
Then we need to pass the counter from the controller to the view

controller:

```
$viewdata = array();
$viewdata['results'] = $this->model->getCitation($term,$start_from,$limit);
$viewdata['pagecounter'] = ((($currentpage*$limit)-$limit)+1);
```

$this->view->getCitation = $viewdata;

view:

```
$viewdata = $this->getCitation();


    $x= $viewdata['pagecounter'];
    while($row = array_shift($viewdata['results'])){
        echo $x++;
        echo $row['title'] . '<br>';
    }
    for($i=1; $i<=$this->getPages; $i++):?>
        <a href="?searchterm=<?php echo $_GET['searchterm'].'&search1=Submit+Query&page=' . $i; ?>">
        <?php echo $i;?></a>
    <?php endfor;?>
```

Comment: If i set the counter on view as you have suggested i introduce php error "undefined variable"

Comment: Then you're issue should be the transfer of variables from the controller to the model, not just the query results, directly... I will try to make the adjustments to my answer